# canvas.drawImage crops image

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-canvas

Hello I have the following image:

[image]

with size 750x554

I load the iamge into a img tag, of the following way:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*"
        onchange="document.getElementById('character').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);">

      <img id="character" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
```

And in order to convert this image into a base64 I use canvas with the following code:

```
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  canvas.width = img.width
  canvas.height = img.height

  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

But the result that I get is a cropped image as you can see here

[image]

How can solve this, and get the image in base64?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the canvas to the size of the image and you need to wait for the image to actually load before trying to draw it.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  const img = document.getElementById('character');
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    
    // show image
    const i = new Image();
    i.src = dataURL;
    document.body.appendChild(i);
  });
  img.src = url;
});
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
<img id="character" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Thats didn't work, I updated the answer with the code and the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think here problem is with your image tag since you have specified the image's width and height as **100**

`<img id="character" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />`

So instead of this just give the actual height and width to image tag.

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: That's is not the problem, if I quit the size attributes, I get the same error